# Won't Xbox Marketplace let me choose my own language?

Tags: xbox-360, assassins-creed-revelations

I just purchased *Assassins Creed: Revelations* on Xbox marketplace and woe, as usual, it assumes I want my damn game in Norwegian. The game is now riddled with horrendously badly translated Norwegian labels and it really really bothers me.

The options lets me change the "game text" to English. If not I would simply delete the game and never look back. But every meta game label is still in Norwegian, and that's not even the point. It seems to me that Xbox marketplace checks my IP address, decides that I live in Norway and assumes that I suck at English and want all my content in Norwegian. It's enraging that I don't get to choose.

Please tell me that I'm wrong and that I can ***COMPLETELY*** change the language of the game and the console to English. (Also please tell me how)

---

***EDIT***: I have actually started to play the game now, and it turns out the only thing about the game that is still English is the voice acting and subtitles. Every label, description, explanation, notice, warning and tutorial is still mind-numbingly badly translated into Norwegian. I have to fix this. I'm 20 minutes into the newest game in my favorite game series and I'm still just getting pissed by the fact that the label on X in an assassination scenario says "Drep" instead of "Assassinate" and similar atrocities. It's unacceptable - please help

Comment: Please tell me by now there's some way to do this!

Answer (score 2):

Alas, the answer of my question lies in [this conversation with Xbox Customer Service](http://pastebin.com/jbPRGe8H):

> **Kesha:** Thanks for waiting, Tomas. Do you have any issue with purchasing content in English?
>   *Tomas:* I would prefer to have everything in English
>   *Tomas:* Including my Xbox Live profile, Xbox Marketplace labels, all my games etc
>   *Tomas:* I don't like Norwegian
>   **Kesha:** Ok, I understand. One moment, let me research to see if there is Assassin's Creed Revelations in English.
>   **Kesha:** Thanks you so much for waiting. Tomas, I was able to find that Assassin Creed Revelations for you region does not have an English version.
>   *Tomas:* In other words, Microsoft is forcing me to play the terrible Norwegian translated version of Assassins Creed?
>   *Tomas:* That can't possibly be good enough
>   *Tomas:* Can you change my region?
>   **Kesha:** I totally understand, as of right now changing location has been disabled.

To summarize, Xbox doesn't let you choose the language of the games you purchase. It sets the language to what ever the main language of the location in which you purchased your Xbox is. I shudder to think of the poor souls who bought their Xbox on vacation to an exotic country.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the physical Xbox. It depends on the region of your *Xbox account*. You can have accounts from different regions cached on the same Xbox at the same time.

Comment: I was told by the Customer Service that the region of the Xbox is locked to wherever I bought it

Comment: Xbox has different colouring systems such as PAL and NTSC, not regions. Each Xbox is locked to one system and only modding (against ToA of course) can change that. Your issue has to do with the region of your *account* as explained in detail by the customer rep in your conversation. You CANNOT change the region of your account (I assume Norway). It's unfortunate that the game wasn't released in English for your region, but one way to get around this is to create a new Xbox account in an English-speaking region and purchase the game again.

Comment: This problem wouldn't have occurred if you had purchased the English PAL retail disc, which is the other way to get around the problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention that if you are concerned about your achievements, you CAN purchase the game from the Marketplace with your new account, download it to your Xbox, then switch back to your Norwegian account to play the game, which will now be in English (pretty sure this trick works).

Comment: I'm still putting the blame on Microsoft here for not separating region from language. I'm pretty sure I'm going to give the PlayStation a chance, and if it's as bad as the Xbox 360 go back to gaming exclusively on the PC

Comment: That's overreacting a bit to me, but you do what you think is fit.

Comment: I just can't play in a world where my games provider restrict me to Norwegian games

Comment: I understand that, but being flexible (using the trick I mentioned) is also an option sometimes.

Comment: @JamesJiao The problem with creating a new account in an English-speaking region is the payment method. If Codemonkey creates e.g. a UK account he will not be able to use a Norwegian credit card because the billing address must match the account's country. This is a mess in Europe generally, where moving countries and expecting content in multiple languages is common, but MS assumes that everyone stays in one country and always wants content in the language of that country. The best solution is to order discs directly from the UK, but Norway is not in the EU so there may be import duty to pay.

Comment: @Pondlife Isn't it what Paypal is for?

Comment: @JamesJiao Interesting idea, and I haven't tried it, but MS [says](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/f/27/t/153161.aspx) that the PayPal and Live account billing addresses must match or you "may have issues". That implies that MS has access to the billing address of the PayPal account too, and I assume they use it to enforce the same restrictions that apply to other payment options. And it's worth noting that PayPal isn't available in all regions, although NO is supported. Some people buy MS points from other regions on eBay, but that seems a bit risky to me.

Comment: @Pondlife Interesting. This might render my option unviable. This has worked for people though I am not sure how they circumvented this issue. It's possible that they have valid addresses in both countries (as do a lot of people including myself), in which case they can have two paypal accounts.

Comment: OMG xbox you suck! In FAR CRY 3, all the labels are Dutch, but the characters are talking in English: "Select the Takedown option". There's no "Takedown" option, because the damn interface is Dutch! Stupid!