# Setting Xbox One language to English, while setting region to a non-English country

Tags: xbox-one

My Xbox profile region is set to The Netherlands, as I live there. However, I'd prefer to use my Xbox One in English. Unfortunately, the settings don't seem to offer the possibility to set the language and region to a combination that doesn't match.

To remedy this so far, I've set my language to English and my region to UK. However, some apps seem to have an issue with this. For example, Xbox Music will complain there's a region mismatch, and I must set my region to The Netherlands. Of course, once I do this, I can only select Dutch as a language.

Is it possible to keep the system language to English, while setting the region to The Netherlands?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72433/wont-xbox-marketplace-let-me-choose-my-own-language

Comment: Didn't they address that issue at the latest E3 conference ? They said they would change that but I don't remember when .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. There is currently no way to fix this problem, as Microsoft has region locked the languages. You could try different regions, such as the U.S. that have an English setting and see if you still encounter the same problems.

Comment: I had found a somewhat related comment [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183520/cant-change-location-to-my-country-on-newly-purchased-xbox-one?rq=1#comment248569_183525), so I was expecting this answer. Real shame :(

Comment: But really, if you want to region lock, fine. But who would region-lock languages?

Comment: I would like to ask you share this link in your answer: https://xbox.uservoice.com/forums/253802-home-settings/suggestions/6028840-don-t-region-lock-the-languages